# Control the radio buttons alignement

Tags: html, css

I use the framework Boostrap and I would like to control the radio buttons alignement.

All the examples I saw to display a responsive list of radio buttons do not manage the alignment. Either they were using labels with same size or a fixed width that keep the alignment but nothing really responsive.

I've tried to use the solution below but with

http://jsfiddle.net/rm7n73ep/`

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
Radio button's label 2
```

Does somebody know how to combine the  property for the responsive behavior and  for a correct alignment of labels and radio button?

Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: In which alignment do you want do display?should there be only one radio button in one row?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `class`:

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.but I din't understand your need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll test.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-5"> Your label </label>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="radio" name="name1" value="0" checked/>
                            <label for="name1">Input 1</label>

                            <input type="radio" name="name2" value="1" />
                            <label for="name2">Input2</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check.